# SLDS : SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /\/: \ at end of pattern

Tags: node.js, salesforce, lightning

I am trying to download and use the Salesforce Lightining Design System for an external app that will be integrated with Salesforce. However, when I follow instructions on GitHub page, after I build the project and issues npm start command I get the following

I have node 9.1.0, npm 5.1.1 installed

output from Powershell on Windows 10

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //: \ at end of pattern
at new RegExp ()
at chunked (C:/Users/klanguedoc/nodedev/design-system/scripts/compile/bundle.js:32:42)
at entryMap.map (C:/Users/klanguedoc/nodedev/design-system/scripts/compile/bundle.js:46:35)
at C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:3018:46
at C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:1379:16
at ArrayMapNode.iterate.HashCollisionNode.iterate [as iterate] (C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:1728:11)
at Map.__iterate (C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:1377:32)
at KeyedIterable.mappedSequence.__iterateUncached (C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:3017:23)
at seqIterate (C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:606:16)
at KeyedIterable.Seq.__iterate (C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\design-system\node_modules\immutable\dist\immutable.js:276:14)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! design-system@2.4.5 previewer: babel-node scripts/previewer
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the design-system@2.4.5 previewer script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-14T14_39_20_960Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! design-system@2.4.5 start: npm run build && npm run previewer
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the design-system@2.4.5 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Here is the ouput from the log file:
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v9.1.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~prestart: objectives@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: objectives@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\objectives\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files\Pervasive Software\PSQL\bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Symantec.cloud\PlatformAgent\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator Manager\1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Bi;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\php\PHP7;C:\composer;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Python27;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\.meteor\;C:\Program Files\sfdx\bin;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\klanguedoc\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\objectives
10 silly lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node ./bin/www' ]
11 silly lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle objectives@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: objectives@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:135:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:224:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:135:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:224:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid objectives@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\klanguedoc\nodedev\objectives
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v9.1.0
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error objectives@1.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the objectives@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Is this something I can fix or the developer
Thanks

Comment: You should probably report the presumed bug on the GitHub project where you found the instructions.

Comment: I did...no one answered :(

Comment: Okay, that would be relevant information to include in the question. It looks like you submitted your issue about 5 hours ago. I would wait a couple business days before assuming they won't respond. Looking at the other issues they seem pretty responsive.

Comment: Okay, it has been 7 days and no response. I will try opening a support ticket directly with SFDC. Even though it is not in Salesforce, they should support their code, right?

Comment: Alright, I would suggest editing that you've done your due diligence to ask along the right channel into your question and providing a link to it. I'll offer an upvote, but I don't have the knowledge to answer this question.

Comment: I recieved a response on GitHub in the repo. They said that they can't reproduce the issue, but they will continue to investigate. I moved on opting to use another framework.